# mysql8 new admin user cant grant proxy

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql8, and see a strange issue.
I have created a new admin user from the root user as follows

```
use mysql
create user 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Somehardpassword1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
flush privileges;
```

I then login with this user and try grant proxy but get permission denied. I can grant proxy permissions with root, but not my new admin user.

```
mysql> GRANT PROXY ON 'mySQL_AD'@'%' TO ''@'';
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost'
mysql>
```

Is there something I am missing? I can grant modify and create everything else, just unable to grant proxy.

The admin users permissions are as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `admin`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION

GRANT APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,AUDIT_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,CLONE_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_APPLIER,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SYSTEM_USER,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN ON *.* TO `admin`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is necessarliy the correct way, but this worked for me:

I could see the root user had an entry in the mysql.proxies_priv table:

```
mysql> select * from mysql.proxies_priv;
+-----------+------+--------------+--------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
| Host      | User | Proxied_host | Proxied_user | With_grant | Grantor | Timestamp           |
+-----------+------+--------------+--------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
| localhost | root |              |              |          1 | boot@   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+-----------+------+--------------+--------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So i cloned the entry and added my admin user

```
insert into mysql.proxies_priv values ('localhost','admin','','','1','boot@','0000-00-00 00:00:00');
 flush privileges;
```

Which gives me the following output

```
mysql> select * from mysql.proxies_priv;
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
| Host      | User  | Proxied_host | Proxied_user | With_grant | Grantor | Timestamp           |
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
| localhost | admin |              |              |          1 | @boot   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| localhost | root  |              |              |          1 | @boot   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+-----------+-------+--------------+--------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```